# How do you determine the "average" of a certain value?

Tags: arithmetic, average

I have checked out the Wikipedia article, but it's too complicated for *me*.

Also, this definition:

> constituting the result obtained by adding together several quantities and then dividing this total by the number of quantities.

does not make clear sense either. First off, constituting means composed of, adding several quantities, and then dividing them also is nonsense.

If I add 60 to 0, I have 60. If I divide 60 by itself I am left with 1. However, dividing anything by itself results in 1, unless you divide by zero.

So please tell me how I get the "average" of something by "adding something", and then "dividing something" by "its quantities"?

That makes no logical sense to me.

Comment: If you add $60$ and $0$, their sum is $60$. The *number of summands* is TWO. So you divide their SUM by their NUMBER (of summands). $60/2 = 30$, which is the average of $60$ and $0$.

Comment: Hmm... the '0' character is really ugly...

Comment: One thing that may be confusing is that people (particularly in e.g. economics reports and the like) talk about averages of what _seem_ like single quantities but are actually representing a large population.  For instance, 'the average home price' is not the average of a _single_ home price but rather an average across the collection of _all_ home prices under consideration.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki So if there's 30 homes for 200,000 U.S.D., the average home goes for $0.00015?

Comment: Andy, no. What is the **SUM** of all the home prices? 200,000 + 200,000 + ... + 200,000 (<---- THIRTY TIMES). Then divide by 30. You'll get $200,000

Comment: The **SUM** is what you get from the total. 30 plus 200,000 is 200,030, and dividing that by 30 is 6,667 dollars.

Comment: You do realize that you are adding two things that are totally unrelated, right? 200k is the price of a house. 30 is the number of houses. Why on earth would you add *those two together??*

Comment: Also, how can the average of 30 200,000 dollar homes be 200,000 dollars? So the average of a fixed value by the sum of its parts always equals the same total mean?

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Because I'm trying to understand "averages", and that's all I understand to go by.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11108/discussion-between-the-chaz-2-0-and-andy-harglesis)

Answer (score 7):

To take the average of $60$ and $0$, you add the quantities $(60 + 0) = 60$, and divide by $2$: $\dfrac {60 + 0}2 = 30$, since you are averaging two quantities: $60$ and $0$.

Indeed, given ***three*** quantities, $a, b, c$, we add them, and divide by $3$.

Average: $$\dfrac{a + b+ c}{3}$$

If we have $n$ quantities, we take their sum, and divide the sum by $n$:

$$\dfrac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n}{n}$$ to find their average.

Comment: So how would that make sense if the quantities are indeterminate? And your "n" example doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: If you have $n$ numbers, add them up and divide by $n$. Seriously, give me your skype number and we'll have this sorted out in20 seconds.

Comment: I really do (honestly) have a fear of talking to random people in a confined, predictable manner, space, or such. I have self-image issues.

Comment: @amWhy: Another TU from me +1

Answer (score 2):

The average of 4, 5 and 8 is $$\frac {4+5+8}{3} = \frac {17}{3} = 5 \frac {2}{3}.$$

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that you are adding the quantities themselves and dividing by **the number of** quantities.

In your example: You add the two quantities $60 + 0 = 60$. Then divide by the number of quantites, which is $2$, to get $$ \frac{60 + 0}{2} = 30 $$

Comment: So ten houses for 50 dollars drive an average of $5 per house?

Comment: @AndyHarglesis If the $50$ dollars is the sum total of the house prices.

Comment: Yes, assuming the total is $50$ dollars (in the numerator) and the number of houses $10$ is in the denominator, giving $\frac{50}{10} = 5$

Comment: Sum? I thought you just added the set of values, and divided them.

Comment: @AndyHarglesis The "sum" is what you get when you add quantities. I.e. the "sum" of $5$ and $7$ is $5 + 7 = 12$

Comment: Right. So what did you add to get that 50? You should have ten things, like $$1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10$$

Comment: Yes, so adding 30 plus 200,000 is 200,030. Ergo, dividing that value 30 times equals 6,667 dollars. That would be the average of 30 200,000 dollar homes?

Comment: No. You add up all the quantities on top. You have $30$ quantities, each is a $200,000$ dollar home. So you add up each of these quantities, that is you add $200,000 + \cdots + 200,000$ 30 times, then divide by $30$. This will simply give $200,000$ as you should expect, since if they are all the same the average should be equal to them.

Comment: Read the answer above, it doesn't imply that.

Answer (score 2):

The wikipedia article says you add the quantities, then divide by the **number** of quantities, by which they mean how many different quantities you have, not their total.

If you have 30 houses, the total value of which is \$200,000, then the average value of each house is \$6666.67.

In this case, your quantities are values of houses, measured in dollars. The total sum of these quantities is \$200,000. You have 30 different houses, each of which has some value associated with it. So the number of quantities you have is 30. Therefore,

$$ \frac{\$200,000}{30 \textrm{houses}} = \$6666.67 \textrm{ per house}. $$

---

You don't take the average of a value, you take the average of a set of values. There are many ways to do this, and it all depends on what you want to do.

Most people think of the average as throwing a bunch of objects in a black box, and then assuming they're all more or less the same, they want to estimate the value of a single object. For example, if you have four pumpkins of different weights on your porch, you might want to estimate the weight of a single pumpkin, assuming they're all the same. Why you'd want to do this, who knows?

There are other ways and interpretations of the average, and they're useful (or not useful) for different reasons.

Comment: None of these answers have made it clear. If average is just adding things and then dividing them by their totals, 30 houses for 200,000 dollars would average less than 1/2 a penny.

Comment: You divide by the total number of things. Let's say you have 4 pumpkins that weigh 4 pounds, 5 pounds, 10 pounds, and 20 pounds. The total weight of all four pumpkins combined is 4+5+10+20 = 39 pounds. Dividing this by the number of pumpkins, and you get 9.75 pounds per pumpkin.

Answer (score 1):

Well basically, if you have (let's say) 3 values $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ the average would be $(x_1+x_2+x_3)/3$. If you have $n$ quantities $x_1,...., x_n$ the average would be $(x_1+....+x_n)/n$. Is it understandable?